# Express by passing my simple auth middleware

Tags: node.js, express

It used to work, and on my other apps it works, but with this new app am developing it's by passing the auth.

Basically it could bring a pop up asking for a username and password, but now it doesn't

Here is my simple auth file

```
 var basicAuth = require('basic-auth');

/**
 * Simple basic auth middleware for use with Express 4.x.
 *
 * @example
 * app.use('/api-requiring-auth', utils.basicAuth('username', 'password'));
 *
 * @param   {string}   username Expected username
 * @param   {string}   password Expected password
 * @returns {function} Express 4 middleware requiring the given credentials
 */
exports.basicAuth = function(username, password) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        var user = basicAuth(req);

        if (!user || user.name !== username || user.pass !== password) {
            res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=Authorization Required');
            return res.send(401);

        }

        next();
    };
};
```

Now this is how i use it,

```
var utils = require('./auth'); // my simple auth file
var user = require('./routes/user');

app.use('/user', user,  utils.basicAuth(config.user['username'], config.user['password']));
```

This is my `./routes/user`

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

 User.find({}).exec(function (error, result) {

        if (error){ throw error;}
        else
        {

        res.render('user/index', {items: JSON.stringify(result)});

        }
          });
});
```

What am i doing wrong

Comment: What is it that do not work? You have to be include more details, *It used to work* is not enough for anyone to know whats the problem is.

Comment: @rckrd  Basically it could bring a pop up asking for a username and password, but now it doesn't

Comment: does the user page render? `routes/user`

Comment: @rckrd it doesn't render a user page, that's not how it works, it simply brings up a pop up asking for credentials after that it takes you to the requested page

Comment: ok, but what happens in `routes/user` could you include that here also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still having issues with the basic-auth library, i was missing the default path `"/"` which simply asks for the login credentials then after it redirects you to the requested page, else it blocks you if logins are incorrect.

This is my default index route file.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET index page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.get('Authorization') !== undefined) {
    res.redirect('/vm'); //path vm is my main home page
  }
  res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

`user` will return the request before `utils.basicAuth` has executed.

Try changing `app.use('/user',...` to:

`app.use('/user',utils.basicAuth(config.user['username'], config.user['password']),user)`;

Below is a example that illustrates your problem.

```
app.get('/example', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('First');
}, function (req, res) {
  // This will not be executed since the request was returned in the first handler 
  res.send('Second')
})
```

Here the second handler is executed:

```
app.get('/middlewarePath', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("Do something awesome here");
  next();
}, function (req, res) {
  // Now second is returned. 
  res.send('Second')
})
```

Comment: That only returns "First" when i access the `example` path, not working

Comment: yes, thats the point of the example. If you want to execute subsequent middleware you should invoke next() in the handler.

Comment: I think i have figured what was missing, the basic-auth was missing the default `path` which is only the `"/"` where it executes auth, thanks for your effort. Much respect for you